# Most efficient way to convert lower to upper case in C?

Tags: c

Using the standard input, the user enters 1 letter. If its a valid lower-case letter, then the program prints out the upper-case version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/toupper/).  If you need to check to see if the input character is lower case first, you can use [`islower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/islower/) to test it.

Comment: Might as well skip the test, since `toupper` won't modify non-lowercase characters.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's why I said "if" - but the original question suggested that the print would only happen if the original was lower (and nothing would be output otherwise).

Comment: For the record, `toupper` depends on the current locale; if the text entered by the user happens to be stored in some sort of Unicode string (say, UTF-8 encoded) then `toupper` wouldn't be an appropriate choice.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: The original questions says "if", not "if and only if", though. So the additional test is really redundant (though of course your explanation of `islower` is correct, and quite possibly useful).

Comment: @KerrekSB It says " If its a valid lower-case letter, then the program prints out the upper-case version." That'd suggest that if it's not a valid lower-case letter, it won't (necessarily) print anything.  If you leave out tolower, entering an 'A' would print an 'A' - not sure if that's desired or not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the encoding; if you merely want to handle ASCII you can exploit the fact that english letters are arranged in a sequence. So your code could look like this:

```
bool isLowerCase( char ch ) {
    return ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z';
}

char toUpperCase( char ch ) {
    return (ch - 'a') + 'A';
}
```

If you are dealing with Unicode strings, you should probably consider using a proper library for this job, such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 32 from the ASCII value typed in

Comment: -1: The OP never said it was an ASCII platform.

Comment: Actually, we are both wrong, since the op only wants it converted to upper case if it is a valid lower case letter...   Of course, he didn't say what he wanted displayed if non-valid

Comment: So what? You can safely use `toupper` on uppercase characters. In fact, since that function already performs all the necessary tests, you don't need to do anything else. The OP never specified what happens when you *don't* input a lower-case character.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') c &= 0xBF;
```

Comment: That is platform and encoding dependent.

Comment: OP said most efficient, not most general.

Comment: "most efficient" implies "correct", though.

Comment: Agreed - but my solution is correct assuming ASCII.  OP didn't specify - perhaps OP can clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a method like .ToUpper(), you can use this method written by me:

```
char* ToUpper(char *lowerText)
{
    int i;

    const int length = strlen(lowerText);

    char *ptrUpperCase = malloc(length + 1);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
            if((lowerText[i] >= 0x61) && (lowerText[i] <= 0x7A))
                    *(ptrUpperCase + i) = lowerText[i] - 0x20;
            else
                    *(ptrUpperCase + i) = lowerText[i];
    }

    *(ptrUpperCase + length) = 0x00;

    return ptrUpperCase;
}
```

and for calling it use:

```
ToUpper("Apple2014");
```

it will return a pointer refer to "APPLE2014".

I hope this will be useful;